# C++ inplace destructor compile warning

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, destructor, compiler-warnings

I am using an inplace destructor in my code, similar to this stripped down piece of code:

```
#include <new>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
};

int main(int, char**) {
    Node* a = reinterpret_cast<Node*>(malloc(sizeof(Node)));
    new(a) Node;

    Node* b = a; 
    b->~Node(); 

    free(a);
}
```

Unfortunately this gives me a warning in Visual Studio 2015, both in Debug and Release:

`warning C4189: 'b': local variable is initialized but not referenced`

It compiles fine though in g++, even with -Wall. Any idea why I get the warning? Might this be a bug in the compiler? b is clearly used in the `b->~Node()` call.

It also seems to compile fine when I change the Node implementation to this:

```
struct Node {
    ~Node() {
    }
};
```

But as far as I can say this should not make a difference.

Comment: Hmm, my guess would be that the optimizer is eliding the call to the default destructor entirely, and then concluding that `b` is never used. Do you see this warning only when you compile an optimized build, or do you see it in unoptimized/debugging builds, too?

Comment: It's also in the debug build

Comment: Interesting. Yeah, I repro with the optimizer enabled and disabled, for both 32-bit and 64-bit builds, and on VS 2010, 2012, and 2015. Looks like a bug to me, unless I'm also missing something obvious. (It *is* eliding the call to the destructor in optimized builds, of course, and in fact, also eliding the call to the constructor. The object code calls only `malloc` and `free`.)

Comment: It is clear as a day that b is being used. Hence this is a compiler bug.

Comment: Also able to reproduce. Adding `~Node() {}` removes warning, however doing `~Node() = default;` produces warning as well (kinda expected).

Comment: I vote for compiler bug, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no standards for compiler warning in C++. Hence each compiler can warn you wherever he wants, **it is a matter of choice**.

In your case the warning does make sense, since the default destructor **may** not consider as a reference (for example: all local variable are defaultly destroyed at the end of their scope).

Answer (score 2):

[Trivial destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor)

The destructor for class T is trivial if all of the following is true:

- The destructor is not user-provided (meaning, it is either implicitly declared, or explicitly defined as defaulted on its first declaration)
- The destructor is not virtual (that is, the base class destructor is not virtual)
- All direct base classes have trivial destructors
- All non-static data members of class type (or array of class type) have trivial destructors.

**A trivial destructor is a destructor that performs no action. Objects with trivial destructors don't require a delete-expression and may be disposed of by simply deallocating their storage.**